# Speedbar mkdir folder

Tags: speedbar

Is there a way to create folders within speedbar?

I am using sr-speedbar and to add a folder I am using the dired mode like:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> (`C-x d`), then <kbd>+</kbd> to create a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`M-x speedbar-create-directory`

or

use the keyboard shortcut:  `M`

In any buffer in Emacs, it is always helpful to type `M-x describe-mode` or `C-h m` and read the `*Help*` buffer that contains useful information regarding what interactive functions are bound to keyboard shortcuts, and so forth ...

In my case, I prefer to read the source code -- I typed `M-x find-library RET speedbar RET` and I searched for the function `make-directory` (which lead me straight to `speedbar-create-directory`), and I also saw `speedbar-create-directory` in the keyboard shortcuts section of the code.